# retrieve data by index on mysql database

Tags: mysql

I would like to retrieve data from a given index. 
Here's the sql code of the database:

```
 CREATE TABLE `test` (
 `index` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`index`),
 UNIQUE KEY `index` (`index`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I can retrieve data from user like this:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE user='bertrand'
```

but when I try with index like this:

```
'index'=1
```

it gives me nothing ! 
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, 
any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: it gives me this error when i remove quotes: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index=1 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: Index is a reserved word... try adding backticks ( ` )

Comment: index is a reserved keyword. Rename that column.

Comment: @user2216280. If you feel an answer answered your question, don't forget to accept it and vote up the answers that pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove quotes. Now it returns nothing because 'index' doesn't equal 1. If you wrap a value it quotes, it will be considered as a string value.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE index=1
```

**EDIT:** Just noticed index is a reserved keyword. Also you have to rename that column.

Comment: renaming it works like a charm !!
thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0):

You can use index in your query, but as it is a reserved keyword, you have to wrap it in backticks, not singlequotes:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE `index`=1
```